# Cant boot VHD created by Disk2VHD

Tags: windows, vhd, windows-virtual-pc

I first created system images using Windows backup then realized that those VHD files cannot be booted using Virtual PC.

So I found the utility Disk2VHD and spent a few hours making a new VHD and tried booting it with Virtual PC but it too cannot boot.

It is giving the error:
PXE-E53: no boot filename received

I followed some instructions found online on going into the Virtual PC settings and ensuring I have the right vhd set up which I do, I also have integration features unavailable.

I then went into the Virtual PC's BIOS and in The Boot menu and it says under Hard Disk Drives [Virtual HD] and in the boot priorities the 1st boot device is the Hard Drive.

This VHD is created from my C: which is my main Windows install (Windows 7 Pro 64-bit)

The whole goal of this is I want to format my drive and install new Windows but I wanted to be able to make a bootable image I could go into later to recover things as needed and see how stuff was setup if I forgot.

Comment: It sounds as if the primary partition on the virtual hard drive isn't active.  It might be worth configuring the virtual machine to boot to the Windows setup DVD and trying a repair operation.

Answer (score 0):

When you converted it over, did you check in the checkbox which allows the file to be used in Virtual PC? I forget what it's called but in there is a checkbox you have to click in before you convert it over.

Also make sure the drive isn't bigger than 127GB or Virtual PC won't recognize it.